# different results when running on different times

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to run this code. In each try the code returns a different result.
Which parameter do I have to change or to add in order to get a consistent result?

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel

classifier = SelectFromModel(
    estimator=RandomForestClassifier(
        n_estimators=3000,
        criterion="gini",
        max_depth=4,
        random_state=0
    ),
    max_features=300
)
```

Comment: The hint is in the name, `RandomForestClassifier`, it's random, the results are going to be different until you set the random seed.

Comment: @ljmc, the code says `random_state=0`, so the random seed has already been set for the random forest

Comment: @ForceBru, my bad yes, I missed it somehow.

Comment: which module are you using ?  (ie. please add the imports)

Comment: @Avital, can you add more information on what you have tried ?

Comment: Are shuffling or splitting your data? If so, did you set the random seed for these operations?

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly I don't shuffling or splitting the data